# Adding Label in a cell in the table and changing the value of the label on button click

Tags: asp.net, uitableview, controls, dynamic-tables

I would like to dynamically create a table with labels and changing the label on the table through button click

I can dynamically provide the table with different labels however i cant change the labels in the table

Here is my code:

.cs

```
protected ovverride void createchildcontrol()
{
    table1.border=1;
}

int counter=1;

for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    row = new htmltablerow();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        label = new label() { id = "label" + counter.tostring() };
        cell = new htmltablecell();
        cell.innertext = label.text = "label" + counter.tostring();
        row.cells.add(cell);
        counter++;
    }
table1.row.add(row);
}
counter = 1;
cell.controls.add(label);
this.controls.add(table1);
}
```

my button code

```
protected void button1_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    label find = cell.findcontrol("label1") as label;
    find.text = "changed"; 
}
```

i have a div `id="placeholder" runatserver="server"` on the other page

I really need to acess the label on my generated HTML table.

Comment: How's the button related to the label/cell? One button per cell?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recreate the table on `pre_init` event. only then it is going to work.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreInit(e);
   //recreate your table here
}
```

You can add Controls dynamically controls in the Page Load event too. But in that case , the Control's State cannot persist across PostBacks. So Dynamic added Controls should exist within the Page Control Hierarchy before the View State is loaded. So creating Controls in Init event makes the Control available in the Hierarchy so that it can persist ViewState.